# Switch ON with PushButton, Switch off with GPIO

Tags: low-voltage

I am looking for a schematic which is capable to switch ON a power Supply to supply a micrcontroller. Then switch off the power supply with a GPIO of this microcontroller.

I have found a lot of schematic on internet. But I have some constraints like (Power supply 0,8v to 1,8V and ultra low power <2uA and load = 200mA)

Another things, if I press the push button a second time, it does not shutdown the power supply.

Edit: The goal is to use a AAA battery (1.2V), but I need 3.3V for microcontroller. So I will use a Boost (30uA without load...). I want to be able to cut OFF power Supply.

I hope found a solution with you !
Sani300

Comment: Edit your question to explain why you can't use sleep mode to switch off and use button press to wake the device up.

Comment: How do you want this to react when the power supply goes out?

Answer (score 1):

A single SR Flip Flop may work, depending on details not stated in your question.

The "set" input will be attached to your pushbutton circuit, the "reset" input will be attached to your microcontroller. You'll need a pull-up/pull-down on the microcontroller pin for when it's not actively driving.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this..?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkP0Tb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

IRC, my actual implementation was something like this (D2 would be problematic with your low voltages I think..):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWyfb.png)</sup>

Comment: But with this solution we have to press the button until microcontroller start-up... !

Comment: @user46510 -- no, when you press the button, M1 is on and R3 turns M2 On. M2 keeps M1 on while MCU is starting up even if you release the button.